# Save a Pandas Dataframe to Databricks using SQLAlchemy

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, databricks

I am trying to save a dataframe to a table in Databricks. The table will be located in the catalog `lending` and schema `default` in databricks.

I first tried to list the columns of an existing table to get an understanding of the interaction between sqlalchemy and databricks. I used the following code and was successful.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

host = '<my-host>'
token = '<my-personal-access-token>'
http_path = '/sql/1.0/warehouses/b4e458b8d76e6b0f'
port = 443
catalog_name = 'lending'
schema_name = 'default'
table_name = 'delinq_users'

db_url = URL.create(
   'databricks',
   username='token',
   password=token,
   host=host,
   port=port,
   database=catalog_name,
   query={'http_path': http_path},
)
engine = create_engine(db_url, echo=True)

metadata = MetaData()
table = Table(table_name, metadata, autoload_with=engine, schema=schema_name)

print([col.name for col in table.columns])
```

The above works and I get back the columns in the table `delinq_users`.

Now, I am using the same mechanism to write a dataframe to a table `cust_kyc_ind` (which doesn't exist yet, but `dataframe.to_sql` creates it). I use the following code -

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

host = '<my-host>'
token = '<my-personal-access-token>'
http_path = '/sql/1.0/warehouses/b4e458b8d76e6b0f'
port = 443
catalog_name = 'lending'
schema_name = 'default'
table_name = 'cust_kyc_ind'

db_url = URL.create(
   'databricks',
   username='token',
   password=token,
   host=host,
   port=port,
   database=catalog_name,
   query={'http_path': http_path},
)
engine = create_engine(db_url, echo=True)

df = pd.read_csv('cust_kyc_ind.csv')

df.to_sql(
   name=table_name,
   schema=schema_name,
   con=engine,
   if_exists='append',
   index=False,
)
```

But, this does not work and I get the following error -

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (databricks.sql.exc.ServerOperationError) PERMISSION_DENIED: User does not have CREATE TABLE on Schema 'main.default'.
```

`main.default` is another available schema in my databricks for which I do not have create table permissions. My question is why is the code trying to use `main.default` instead of `lending.default` (as it uses in the first code).

Answer (score 0):

While I have not tested this, it looks like the issue is with the `to_sql` method not using the `catalog` name when addressing the table. In your call to `to_sql`, tack on the catalog to the schema name (like so: `schema=catalog_name+schema_name` and try if it works.